# Best practices for rolling back transactions in Spring 3/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions, spring-mvc

Referencing [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative):

> Any RuntimeException will trigger rollback, and any checked Exception will not

Referencing [javapractices.com](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129)

> Unchecked exceptions :
>
> - represent defects in the program (bugs) - often invalid arguments
>     passed to a non-private method. To
>     quote from The Java Programming
>     Language, by Gosling, Arnold, and
>     Holmes : "Unchecked runtime exceptions
>     represent conditions that, generally
>     speaking, reflect errors in your
>     program's logic and cannot be
>     reasonably recovered from at run
>     time."
> - are subclasses of RuntimeException, and are usually implemented
>     using IllegalArgumentException, NullPointerException,
>     or IllegalStateException
> - a method is not obliged to establish a policy for the unchecked exceptions
>     thrown by its implementation (and they almost always do not do so)
>
> Checked exceptions :
>
> - represent invalid conditions in areas outside the immediate control of
>     the program (invalid user input,
>     database problems, network outages,
>     absent files)
> - are subclasses of Exception
> - a method is obliged to establish a policy for all checked exceptions
>     thrown by its implementation (either
>     pass the checked exception further up
>     the stack, or handle it somehow)

If during my business logic I discover a problem and I want to rollback the changes, I have to throw a new RuntimeException?  It's not really a RuntimeException (unchecked exception) since I've identified it in the logic.  Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding these concepts?

**My real question**, what's best practices for rolling back a transaction in my @Transactional service methods?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using checked exceptions you simply add them to the `rollbackFor` property of your `@Transactional` annotation.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { MyInvalidUserException.class, MyApplicationException.class })
public void method() throws MyInvalidUserException,  MyApplicationException { 
    ... 
    ... 
}
```

etc.

*org.life.java's* answer also works fine.  It's an academic decision if you want to intermix programmatic transaction management into your declarative transactions or keep it strictly declarative.

Comment: How can I return something from my method if I throw an exception? Additionally,  throwing an exception is quite costly. Isn'the there any way to manually rollback the transaction without firing an exception?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet One could counter that if you're purposely rolling things back as part of a non-exceptional business process flow, the costs associated with rollbacks in an RDBMS dwarf by orders of magnitude any real or perceived cost of an exception on a modern JVM, and the whole design ought to be revisited.  Regardless, if you don't like the way declarative transactions work... don't use them.  The feature is by no means your only option.  You can still use plain old roll-your-own hibernate session transactions.

Answer (score 7):

Either roll back programmatically from within:

```
@Transactional
public void commit() {
  try {
    // some business logic...
  } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
    // trigger rollback programmatically
    TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
  }
}
```

or mark the exception for rollback and handle it from the caller:

```
@Transactional(rollBackFor = TransactionException.class)
public void commit() throws ConstraintViolationException{
    try {
    // some business logic...
  } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
    // handle the exception 
    // re-throw for rollback
    new TransactionException(e);
  }
}

public void doCommit(){
  try {
    commit()
  } catch (TransactionException e){
    // do nothing as already handled
  }
}
```

I prefer the former as it keeps the code simpler, but it is [discouraged](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back) according to Spring docs:

> Programmatic rollback is available should you absolutely need it, but
>   its usage flies in the face of achieving a clean POJO-based
>   architecture.

Answer (score 4):

It should be like

```
@Transactional
public void method () throws YourCustomException  {
   try{
           //logic  
   }catch(Exception ex){
             TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()
                        .setRollbackOnly();
             throw(new YourCustomException(ex.getMessage()));
   }
}
```

Comment: ... and *why* should it be like that?

Comment: @meriton It will work for all the case , I mean your purpose of showing that this service is throwing this exception will get solved as well as your transactional things will be taken care also

Answer (score 2):

I think it's safe to say that there are different opinions about which exceptions should be checked. For instance, consider this excerpt from [Introduction to the Spring Framework](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364527/Introduction-to-the-Spring-Framework):

> The Spring data access exception
>   hierarchy is based on unchecked
>   (runtime) exceptions. Having worked
>   with Spring on several projects I'm
>   more and more convinced that this was
>   the right decision.
>
> Data access exceptions not usually
>   recoverable. For example, if we can't
>   connect to the database, a particular
>   business object is unlikely to be able
>   to work around the problem. One
>   potential exception is optimistic
>   locking violations, but not all
>   applications use optimistic locking.
>   It's usually bad to be forced to write
>   code to catch fatal exceptions that
>   can't be sensibly handled. Letting
>   them propagate to top-level handlers
>   like the servlet or EJB container is
>   usually more appropriate. All Spring
>   data access exceptions are subclasses
>   of DataAccessException, so if we do
>   choose to catch all Spring data access
>   exceptions, we can easily do so.
>
> Note that if we do want to recover
>   from an unchecked data access
>   exception, we can still do so. We can
>   write code to handle only the
>   recoverable condition. For example, if
>   we consider that only an optimistic
>   locking violation is recoverable, we
>   can write code in a Spring DAO as
>   follows:
>
> try { // do work } catch
>   (OptimisticLockingFailureException ex)
>   { // I'm interested in this } If
>   Spring data access exceptions were
>   checked, we'd need to write the
>   following code. Note that we could
>   choose to write this anyway:
>
> try { // do work } catch
>   (OptimisticLockingFailureException ex)
>   { // I'm interested in this } catch
>   (DataAccessException ex) { // Fatal;
>   just rethrow it } One potential
>   objection to the first example - that
>   the compiler can't enforce handling
>   the potentially recoverable exception
>   - applies also to the second. Because we're forced to catch the base
>   exception (DataAccessException), the
>   compiler won't enforce a check for a
>   subclass
>   (OptimisticLockingFailureException).
>   So the compiler would force us to
>   write code to handle an unrecoverable
>   problem, but provide no help in
>   forcing us to deal with the
>   recoverable problem.
>
> Spring's use of unchecked data access
>   exceptions is consistent with that of
>   many - probably most - successful
>   persistence frameworks. (Indeed, it
>   was partly inspired by JDO.) JDBC is
>   one of the few data access APIs to use
>   checked exceptions. TopLink and JDO,
>   for example, use unchecked exceptions
>   exclusively. Hibernate switched from
>   checked to unchecked exceptions in
>   version 3.

Data access exceptions are clearly outside the immediate control of the program, so according to javapractices, they should be checked. But the people at spring source differ. And I trust their judgment more than javapractices.

Therefore, I see nothing wrong with throwing an unchecked exception to indicate that the transaction should be rolled back. Of course, you can also use checked exceptions, and configure the aspect to roll back for them, too. (see Affe's answer for details)

Answer (score 2):

Came across this url for handling checked & unchecked exceptions , managing transactions:
It's not the annotation driven approach but it's good.

http://javasight.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/understanding-spring-transaction-management-with-checked-and-unchecked-exceptions/