# Will the rollbackFor attribute in Spring Data will work even if I do a try catch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I was reading about the rollbackFor attribute when using JPA.

Right now my code is this

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
   public void newUser(User user) {
        try{
            userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        }catch(Exception e){
            //log exception
        }
        return;
    }
```

As far as I know, the rollbackFor will work when an exception is captured... is this the proper way to do it? or the try catch should not be there?

Thanks.

Comment: `Transactional` is a Spring annotation, not a JPA annotation.

Comment: I cannot imagine how the `@Transactional` annotation could affect behavior when an exception is *caught* by the annotated method.  I am therefore inclined to assume that the `rollbackFor` attribute is about exceptions that are *thrown* (directly or indirectly) by the annotated method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Transactional Annotation rollbackFor:**
>    Defines zero (0) or more exception classes, which must be subclasses of Throwable, indicating which exception types must cause a transaction rollback.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#rollbackFor--

**Also, We should not suppress/eat the exception within the transactional method, rather we need to throw the Exception out from the method in order to roll back the database transaction:**

Please find the proper implementation below:

```
     @Transactional(readOnly = false, 
      propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
      public void newUser(User user) throws Exception {
        try{
            userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
         } catch(Exception e){
           throw new Exception("Unable to Save User Object ",e);
        }
     }
```

**You can also refer the below link for handling exceptions for Transactional annotation:**

[Best practices for rolling back transactions in Spring 3/Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402506/best-practices-for-rolling-back-transactions-in-spring-3-hibernate)

Comment: It is highly advisable to use exception chaining in cases such as this, so that the nature and context of the original exception is not lost: `throw new Exception("Unable to Save User Object", e);`.

Comment: It would also be better to throw (and probably also to declare) a more specific exception than `Exception`.

Comment: Agreed with your comments.

Comment: but using this way of throwing the exception would then let me have a rollback?

Comment: The transaction will be rolled back for all the exceptions given under rollbackFor attribute. You can also refer the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402506/best-practices-for-rolling-back-transactions-in-spring-3-hibernate

Comment: I appreciate if someone specifies the reason for downvoting this answer.

Comment: even if you catch all exception? nobody specifies that :s

Comment: yes, any Exception type (Subclass of Throwable), thrown by the transactional method.

Comment: why do you have try-catch block at all? what is added value?